# Getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in my script

Tags: python, string

while running this program I am getting the error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable". Any ideas?

```
def caesar_encrypt(text,num):
    i = ""

    for i in text:
        if not i.isalpha():
            i += i
        elif i.isupper():
            i += i(((ord(i) + num - 65) %26) + 65)
        else:
            i += i(((ord(i) + num - 97) %26) + 97)
    return i

s=input("please enter the message: ")
step=int(input("now enter the step "))

encrypted_msg=caesar_encrypt(s, num)
print(encrypted_msg)
```

Comment: `encrypted_msg=caesar_encrypt(s, num)` -> `encrypted_msg=caesar_encrypt(s, step)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! How's `i( ... bunch of other stuff ... )` supposed to work? The error is clear: you're calling a string like `"x"()`, which minimally reproduces the problem. `i` is a string. You have a variable aliasing problem, seemingly, with the loop var overwriting the outer `i`. Only use `i` for integers and indexes, not for strings or elements. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I think you should simply remove `i` which you have before `()`  in `i += i(...)`

Comment: Do you have to be able to decode an encoded string too?

Comment: yes but i can got it to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the posted code. First, the call to `caesar_encrpyt()` needs to look like `caesar_encrypt(s, step)`. Secondly, you have two local variables in that function defined as `i`; that one that's being returned should be changed to a more descriptive name. Lastly, and what's causing your error, is `i += i(((ord(i) + num - 97) %26) + 97)` and `i += i(((ord(i) + num - 65) %26) + 65)`. Here `i` is a string and as the error suggests, is not callable; instead, this should be calling `chr()` to convert that result back to a character.

This is what the fixed code should look like:
`

```
def caesar_encrypt(text,num):
    encoded_msg = ""

    for i in text:
        if not i.isalpha():
            encoded_msg += i
        elif i.isupper():
            encoded_msg += chr(((ord(i) + num - 65) %26) + 65)
        else:
            encoded_msg += chr(((ord(i) + num - 97) %26) + 97)
    return encoded_msg

s=input("please enter the message: ")
step=int(input("now enter the step "))

encrypted_msg=caesar_encrypt(s, step)
print(encrypted_msg)
```

`